# Detecting client screen resolution

Tags: apache-flex

How can i detect my client's screen resolution .. in Flex??

Zee

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
//To know horizontal-screen-resolution
var screenResolutionX:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;

//To know vertical screen-resolution
var screenResolutionY:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```

Here's more info on the [Capabilities API](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/Capabilities.html).

Answer (score 2):

```
Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
Capabilities.screenResolutionY;
```

[Here is the documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/system/Capabilities.html) on the Capabilities class, and all of the various information that can be acquired.